# Al oprimir tab llenar campos del formulario: ajax - laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-9

Necesito realizar una búsqueda por numero cedula ingresándola en un input y al oprimir la tecla tab se ejecuta una petición Ajax y obtiene los datos de ese paciente y los coloca en lo inputs correspondientes al formulario.

El error que me sale es 404 cuando ingreso al cedula y oprimo la tecla tab

```
GET localhost/eventos/buscarPaciente1297483768 404 (Not Found)
```

Esta es la ruta que hace la peticion:

```
Route::get('eventos/buscarPaciente/{no_documento?}',[EventoController::class, 'buscarPaciente'])->name('eventos.buscar');
```

Este es el controlador que ejecuta la funcion `EventoController.php`

```
public function buscarPaciente($no_documento='')
{
    $q = $no_documento;
    if($q){
        $paciente = DB::connection('gomedisys')->table('users as u')->distinct()
        ->select('u.documentNumber as identificacion','aseg.shortBusinessName as aseguradora','uca.name as genero')
        ->selectRaw("CONCAT_WS(' ',u.firstGivenName,u.secondGiveName,u.firstFamilyName,u.secondFamilyName) AS paciente")
        ->selectRaw("FORMAT(up.birthDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') as fecha_nacimiento")
        ->join('userPeople as up','u.idUser','=','up.idUser')
        ->join('userConfAdministrativeSex as uca','up.idAdministrativeSex','=','uca.idAdministrativeSex')
        ->join('encounters as e','u.idUser','=','e.idUserPatient')
        ->join('encounterRecords as er','e.idEncounter', '=','er.idEncounter')
        ->join('users as aseg','er.idPrincipalContractee','=','aseg.idUser')
        ->where('u.isPatient',1)->where('u.isActive',1)
        ->where('u.documentNumber','=',$q)
        ->take(1)->get();
    
    }

    return response()->json($paciente, 200);
}
```

Esta es la vista donde esta el formulario con la peticion ajax

```
<form action="{{ route('eventos.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" autocomplete=off
    data-parsley-validate id='validarForm'>
    @csrf
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="">Identificacion del paciente </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="buscarPaciente(event, this, this.value)"
                            name="no_documento" id="no_documento" placeholder="ejemplo: 23456734">
                        @error('no_documento')
                            <small class="text-danger">
                                {{ $message }}
                            </small>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="">Paciente</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="paciente" name="paciente" readonly>
                        @error('paciente')
                            <small class="text-danger">
                                {{ $message }}
                            </small>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Genero</label>
                        <input type="text" name="genero" id="genero" class="form-control"
                            aria-describedby="nombre" value="" readonly>
                        @error('genero')
                            <small class="text-danger">
                                {{ $message }}
                            </small>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Aseguradora</label>
                        <input type="text" id="aseguradora" name="aseguradora" readonly class="form-control"
                            aria-describedby="nombre" value="">
                        @error('aseguradora')
                            <small class="text-danger">
                                {{ $message }}
                            </small>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-center">
        <div class="col-12" id="guardar">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-xs-4">Guardar</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-4">Limpiar</button>
            <a class="btn btn-danger col-xs-4" href="{{ route('eventos.index') }}">Cancelar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@push('js')
    <script>
        // Escuchar cuando el campo pierda foco
        $('#no_documento').on('blur', function(e) {
            // Ejecuta la función para la petición AJAX
            buscarPaciente($(this), $(this).val());
        });

        // Escuchar teclas Enter y Tab
        $('#no_documento').on('keydown', function(e) {
            if (e.key == 'Enter' || e.key == 'Tab') {
                // Se debe cancelar el evento para evitar:
                // ENTER: Envío de formulario
                // TAB: Pasar foco al siguiente campo
                e.preventDefault();
                // Ejecutas la función para la petición AJAX
                buscarPaciente();
            }
        });

        // obtengo el no_documento con $('#no_documento').val()
        function buscarPaciente() {
            let no_documento = $('#no_documento').val();
            if (no_documento != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "{{route('eventos.buscar')}}"+no_documento,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(resultado) {
                        console.log(resultado);
                        if (resultado == 0) {
                            $('#no_documento').val('');
                        } else {
                            $('#no_documento').removeClass('has-error');

                            $("#resultado_error").html(resultado.error);

                            if (resultado.existe) {
                                $("#no_documento").val(resultado.datos.identificacion);
                                $("#paciente").val(resultado.datos.paciente);
                                $("#genero").val(resultado.datos.genero);
                                $("#aseguradora").val(resultado.datos.aseguradora);
                                $("#fecha_nacimiento").val(resultado.datos.fecha_nacimiento);
                                $("#no_documento").focus();
                            } else {
                                $("#no_documento").val('');
                                $("#paciente").val('');
                                $("#genero").val('');
                                $("#aseguradora").val('');
                                $("#fecha_nacimiento").val('');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
@endpush
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que te falta un /

GET `localhost/eventos/buscarPaciente/1297483768`

en lugar de:

GET `localhost/eventos/buscarPaciente1297483768`

Comment: Gracias, ya lo organice pero me trae vacío la petición :/ y si lo hago colocando directamente el numero si me trae. No se que esta fallando

Comment: te toca analizar el query, de seguro no te esta consiguiendo data debido a los joins, alguno de ellos no debe estar cumpliendo el criterio.